# uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Observing (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have developed a web application using ruby on rails. I have upgraded my rails version from 3.2 to 4.0 and I am getting the below error while starting my server.

**Error :**

> /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/dynamoid-0.6.1.1/lib/dynamoid/config.rb:11:in `<module:Config>': uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Observing (NameError)
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/dynamoid-0.6.1.1/lib/dynamoid/config.rb:8:in`'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/dynamoid-0.6.1.1/lib/dynamoid/config.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/dynamoid-0.6.1.1/lib/dynamoid.rb:21:in`'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `each'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in`block in require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:63:in `each'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:63:in`require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/src/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite/rails-root/config/application.rb:88:in`'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/src/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite/rails-root/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/src/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite/rails-root/config.ru:3:in`block in '
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`initialize'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/src/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite/rails-root/config.ru:in `new'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/src/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite/rails-root/config.ru:in`'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`new_from_string'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in`build_app_and_options_from_config'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in`wrapped_app'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in`start'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/bin/rackup:23:in`load'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/FCLaunchRequirementWebsite-1.0/runtime/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
>   /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/BrazilRake-1.1/runtime/ruby2.1.x/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/amazon/brazil/ruby.rb:98:in`exec_build_script': Command exited with status 1!! (RuntimeError)
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/BrazilRake-1.1/runtime/bin/brazilrake:61:in `block in <main>'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/BrazilRake-1.1/runtime/bin/brazilrake:48:in`each'
>       from /home/lakhwani/FCLaunchRequirement/env/BrazilRake-1.1/runtime/bin/brazilrake:48:in `'

Can any one help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How did you update the rails project to use rails 4? For rails 4.2 and below, if you want to update it, just add the rails version you want in the Gemfile of the app and run `rails app:update`. Follow [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html).